# Dynamic cases for switch statement (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, switch-statement

I hope this is a new question (I haven't find it).
My problem is that i want to do something like that in objective-c:

```
switch (indexPath.row){
for (int i=0; i < value; i++){
    case i:
    //do something
    break;
}
}
```

But I found a documentation that says this is not possible, and obviously program don't compile. Is there any alternative or trick to do this?

thanks you very much for the help

(now there are also the 2 lines that I forgot earlier)

Comment: what would you like achieve here eventually?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible,  `case` takes only const values.

But you can use this macro for that purposes

```
#define CASE(arg)                       if (__s__ == (arg)) 
#define SWITCH(s)                       for (int __s__ = (s); ; )
#define DEFAULT
```

***Example of usage***

```
int value = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++){
    SWITCH(i) {
        CASE (i) {
            break;
        }
        DEFAULT {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `switch` is missing.

```
for (int i=0; i < value; i++){
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever test it?